# how to shape vertical line with curved at corners in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Simply i attached the required output image.w ithin the braces, i need a textviews..
[image]

i  tried with below code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2  col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 nopadding">
    <div class="card weather" widget="">
        <div class="card-header">
            <span class="heading">Criminal Records</span>
            <div class="widget-controls">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-xs" type="button" routerLink="/overview">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <search-details [searchDetails]='details'></search-details>
        <div class="card  bottom-15">
            <div class="card-block text_yellow searchfont">{{data.length ? data.length : ''}} Possible Criminal
                <span *ngIf="data.length == 1">Record</span>
                <span *ngIf="data.length > 1">Records</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="text-overflow">IMPORTANT: Due to varying quality of source data, records displayed may not pertain to your subject. Independent
                    verification is highly recommended. Criminal record results in FOREWARN may be limited due to strict
                    matching logic. Additional records may exist that fall outside FOREWARN's strict matching process.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-xs criminal-info-button" (click)="openCriminalImportantNote()" type="button">More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="card-block widget-body buttons">
                <div class="row" *ngFor="let record of data; let i = index">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 bottom-15">
                        <div class="card text_yellow">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                Record: {{i+1}}
                                <p class="propname">Source: {{ record.sourceName }}</p>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <div *ngIf="record.offenseDate" class="row">
                                            <label class="col-5 col-sm-4 text-truncate text-gray">Offense Date: </label>
                                            <div class="col-7 col-sm-7">{{ record.offenseDate }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div *ngIf="record.chargesFiledDate " class="row">
                                            <label class="col-5 col-sm-4 text-truncate text-gray">Charges Filed Date: </label>
                                            <div class="col-7 col-sm-7">{{ record.chargesFiledDate }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div *ngIf="record.convictionDate" class="row">
                                            <label class="col-5 col-sm-4 text-truncate text-gray">Conviction Date: </label>
                                            <div class="col-7 col-sm-7">{{ record.convictionDate }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-5 col-sm-4 text-truncate text-gray">Case Type: </label>
                                            <div class="col-7 col-sm-7">{{ record.caseType }}</div>
                                            <label class="col-5 col-sm-4 text-truncate text-gray">Description: </label>
                                            <div class="col-7 col-sm-7">{{ record.description }}</div>
                                            <label class="col-5 col-sm-4 text-truncate text-gray">Disposition: </label>
                                            <div class="col-7 col-sm-7">{{ record.disposition }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <p>
                                            <b>
                                                <u>Match Key</u>
                                            </b>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-9 col-sm-6">FirstName: </label>
                                            <div *ngIf="record.matchKeys && record.matchKeys.firstName" class="col-3 col-sm-6 color-green">&#10003;
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-9 col-sm-6">LastName: </label>
                                            <div *ngIf="record.matchKeys && record.matchKeys.lastName" class="col-3 col-sm-6 color-green">&#10003;
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-9 col-sm-6">MInitial: </label>
                                            <div *ngIf="record.matchKeys && record.matchKeys.mInitial" class="col-3 col-sm-6 color-green">&#10003;
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-9 col-sm-6">BirthDate: </label>
                                            <div *ngIf="record.matchKeys && record.matchKeys.dob" class="col-3 col-sm-6 color-green">&#10003;
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-9 col-sm-6">Address: </label>
                                            <div *ngIf="record.matchKeys && record.matchKeys.address" class="col-3 col-sm-6 color-green">&#10003;
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-9 col-sm-6">State: </label>
                                            <div *ngIf="record.matchKeys && record.matchKeys.state" class="col-3 col-sm-6 color-green">&#10003;
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im trying to add vertical lines with curved at corners in html but i dont have any idea how to add vertical lines in html with curved shape at corners. so can any one help me to solve this.

Please can any one help me to solve this.

Comment: Please consider putting the relevant code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share it so that everyone has a better idea of what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `borders` and `border-radius` to achieve what you want, adjust `border-radius` to fit your needs, code will be like follow:

```css
div {
  width: 70px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Two ways:

**Method #1:** *borders* on containing element & "block-out" *pseudo-elements*

This method uses *[pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)* to "block-out" the containing element's top and bottom borders.

```css
body {
    background: gold;
}

.containing {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: gold;
    position: relative;
}

.containing:before {
    content: "";
    width: 80%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -1px;
    margin: auto;
    background: gold;
    z-index: 1;
}

.containing:after {
    content: "";
    width: 80%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -1px;
    margin: auto;
    background: gold;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="containing"></div>
```

**Method #2:** *borders* on *pseudo-elements*

This method also uses *[pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)* but to draw the borders themselves allowing *transparent* gaps to the top and bottom of the containing elements; which will be useful if you need these elements to behave as intended against *any `background-color`*.

```css
body {
    background: white; /* to demonstrate transparent background */
}

.containing {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: gold;
    position: relative;
}

.containing:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

.containing:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="containing"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as everyone here mentions already, `border` and `border-radius` is what you are looking for.

```
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 20px;
```

here is a simple fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/suvartheec/obhL9aca/